# Pyright が型の名前につけるアットマーク @ は標準化されていますか？

Tags: python, python3

別の（削除された）質問について調べているときに、Python の type hints を使った Pyright による型推論について、同じ名前の TypeVar を区別して表示するため `_T@foo` のようにアットマークをデリミタにしつつ型の名前に TypeVar のスコープをくっつけて表示していることを知りました。

- 実装: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/4e22927305fc119a6ac1d5a8a3819439456d5e4b/packages/pyright-internal/src/analyzer/types.ts#L2116
- この機能が導入されたコミット: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/commit/27e09f2ef5b38bb2b427839649e48a9eab69098d

一方で、この機能が PEP として標準化されているのは見つけられませんでした。また、Pyright の機能としてのドキュメントは、クラスの `Self` に関する部分については書かれているのを見つけましたが ([docs](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/4e22927305fc119a6ac1d5a8a3819439456d5e4b/docs/type-concepts.md#inferred-type-of-self-and-cls-parameters))、一般の話は見つけられませんでした。

この機能は何かしら標準化されていたり、標準化に向けた取り組みがなされていたりするでしょうか？　便利そうなので統一されたルールがあれば知りたいなと思っています。